# Objective-C, iOS SDK, How to save UITableView Cell image checkmark

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save the image state of the cell as to when the user exits the app or leaves the view, the image is still saved. I'm thinking NSUserDefaults maybe, what's the best way?
Thanks.

Currently I have this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

if (cell.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxfull.png"]){
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"];
}else if(cell.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"])

{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxfull.png"];
   // [alert show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use NSUserDefaults for a few things, but I wouldn't save them individually. I would probably store each cell in an array. It will make saving multiple cells much easier.

```
NSMutableArray *checkState = [[NSArray alloc] init];
if([cell.imageView.image highlighted]) {
   [checkState addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
} else
   [checkState addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

Then when you load your table:
NSArray cellState = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourSavedKey"];
[cell.imageView.image setHighlighted:[cellState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: I see, so put the check state in did select row at index? and the rest in view? But when do I call the defaults??

Comment: I would maybe put that in a property and just fill it up in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how many cells you have that you're trying to save the content of. If it's a few, it's not a big deal to do in NSUserDefaults, but if it's lots more, maybe Core Data would be a better solution for you.

If you wanted to use NSUserDefaults, you probably want to set a BOOL in there to indicate whether the checkbox is on or off (since you only have two states). So:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"someUniqueIdentifier"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give an example how you would use or were you'd put NSUserDefaults above? In an if statement? Table cells get added or deleted by the user, and that works fine, just the image part I'm not sure how to save

Comment: It would really only work nicely if they were some static cells that weren't added or deleted. Since your user is adding and deleting, I would suggest to use CoreData. That way you can make your own entity (Class) for each cell and store as little or as much data in there as you want.